# Using GROUP BY in MySQL Join Table

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join, join

i have problem using JOIN between two tables, 
Here is my table :

**patient table**

```
........................................
uid | no_mr     | name
........................................
1   | 1101      | Eko
2   | 1102      | John Doe
```

**visit table**

```
..............................................
uid | vcode         | patient_id
..............................................
1   | V-20130725143528  | 1
2   | V-20130726132308  | 2
3   | V-20130726142907  | 2
4   | V-20130726144436  | 1
```

How to display patient data based on visit table, 
and sorted in descending order by visit.uid.

Here is my query,

```
SELECT patient . * , visit.uid
FROM patient
LEFT JOIN visit ON patient.uid = visit.patient_id
WHERE patient.uid >1
GROUP BY patient.no_mr
ORDER BY visit.uid DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

When i run that query, i have this value.

```
.......................................
uid | no_mr     | name
.......................................
2   | 1102      | John Doe
1   | 1101      | Eko
```

I want like this,  display the patient data that have new visit data.

```
.......................................
uid | no_mr     | name
.......................................
1   | 1101      | Eko
2   | 1102      | John Doe
```

Please help, thank you..

Comment: It not works when have more than two patient records.
This is my patient data, and visit data :
[IMAGE](http://imageshack.com/scaled/large/40/65te.jpg)

The `GROUP BY` just compare in the first three rows.,How to handle that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT q.* FROM (
SELECT patient . * , visit.uid AS visit_uid
FROM patient
LEFT JOIN visit ON patient.uid = visit.patient_id
ORDER BY visit_uid DESC 

) q GROUP BY q.uid ORDER BY q.visit_uid DESC 

LIMIT 0 , 10
```

[**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd8003/5)

Comment: Still not works when i have more than two patients and visit data. Here is my [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd8003/3)